# Ansible - Set Playbook level Environment variable, but after defining some tasks

Tags: ansible, environment-variables, task

I want to set a playbook level environment, but after I execute a couple of tasks.  I have found that I could define a playbook level environment variable before definition of any tasks or task level environment variables.  But, I haven't found how can I set-up an environment variable that can be used by all tasks following a task.

```
- name: server properties
  hosts: kafka_broker
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_extra_args: "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
    ansible_host_key_checking: false
    date: "{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S') }}"
    copy_to_dest: "/export/home/kafusr/kafka/secrets"
    server_props_loc: "/etc/kafka"
    secrets_props_loc: "{{ server_props_loc }}/secrets"

  environment:
    CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY: "{{ extract_key2 }}"

  tasks:

    - name: Create a directory if it does not exist
      file:
        path: "{{ copy_to_dest }}"
        state: directory
        mode: '0755'

    - name: Find files from "{{ server_props_loc }}"
      find:
        paths: /etc/kafka/
        patterns: "server.properties*"
        # ... the rest of the task
      register: etc_kafka_server_props

    - name: Find files from "{{ secrets_props_loc }}"
      find:
        paths: /etc/kafka/secrets
        patterns: "*"
        # ... the rest of the task
      register: etc_kafka_secrets_props

    - name: Copy the files
      copy:
        src: "{{ item.path }}"
        dest: "{{ copy_to_dest }}"
        remote_src: yes
      loop: "{{ etc_kafka_server_props.files + etc_kafka_secrets_props.files }}"

    - name: set masterkey content value
      set_fact:
        contents: "{{ lookup('file', '/export/home/kafusr/kafka/secrets/masterkey.txt') }}"
        extract_key2: "{{ contents.split('\n').2.split('|').2|trim }}"
```

I want to set `CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY` after the set_facts task

Is it possible to set playbook level environment variable, but after defining some tasks

Thank you

**UPDATE**

Initially, when I was executing the playbook as originally defined,  I was getting the error

```
fatal: [kafkaserver1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The field 'environment' has an invalid value, 
which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'extract_key2' is undefined"}
```

which was expected as the variable extract_key2 was not set - before copying the files to desired directory.

After @Zeitounator's suggestion, when I added default to the environment variable's definition,

```
CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY: "{{ extract_key2 | default('') }}"
```

I now get a different error

The new error is

```
TASK [set masterkey content value] ******************** fatal: [kafkaserver1]: FAILED! => 
{"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'contents' is undefined\n\n
The error appears to be in '/export/home/kafuser/tmp/so-71538207-question.yml': line 43, column 7, but may\n
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n
- name: set masterkey content value\n      ^ here\n"}
```

Getting this on all 3 brokers in the console and I checked the file it exists

I did do a cat on that file, copying the path from error to make sure there is no typo, and the contents of that file are displayed on console.

**Update 2**

I am trying to figure out how to use slurp to get the info, with the same approach as @Zeitounator's example about using lookup.

This is what I am trying.  The current definition, is of course, erroneous. Just wanted to show what I am trying to do. But, can it be done for slurp and am I on the right path?

```
    environment:

    CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY: >-
      {{
        (
          ((slurp: src: /export/home/z8tpush/kafka/secrets/masterkey.txt)['content'] | b64decode ).split('\n').2.split('|').2|trim 
        )
      }}
```

@Zeitounator -  Will you be able to direct me to an example where a slurp or fetch module is defined to set-up an environment variable and where the value will get updated after the tasks that create the file are executed,  similar to what you have shown with lookup filter?  I would really appreciate it.

***Note:***

Ultimately, I want to use ansible to create a new kafka user using confluents CLI commands ( using shell or command module ), verify it in my directory and once satisfied, I will encrypt the security.properties file using the masterkey and copy it to the appropriate location where confluent is installed.

Comment: What is actually wrong when your run the above ? You play level definition will be evaluated every time it is used so your environment will reflect the change getting the value calculated in `set_fact` in the following tasks.

Comment: I need to set-up `CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY` variable as an environment variable after the last *set_facts* task and that would be used as an environment variable for the next steps I would be adding  From what I understand,  if I define it in a task, then it gets applied to only that task, not ALL the subsequent tasks.

Comment: You did not get my comment right. Just keep your playbook as it is and write more tasks after your set_fact. They will pick up the new value for the environment varialble and that one will be evaluated on every call.

Comment: `CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY: "{{ extract_key2 | default('') }}"`

Comment: `.... the new error is ....` <= what was the first error ? Also I think you have enough reputation to know that comments are not made for large portion of code and error. Please edit your question and make it [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: @Zeitounator - Removed comments and updated the question

Comment: @Zeitounator or other Ansible experts - Is it possible with slurp, the way I am trying?

Comment: `slurp` is a module, not a filter. But you can use the result in your above query in place of the file lookup. An other option is to `fetch` the files locally then lookup their contents as you are currently doing.

Comment: Can you give some guidance on how to do that?  Such that I can still define the Environment variable at playbook level

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you can

- With [Ansible Configuration Settings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html) set environment variables globally
- [Setting the remote environment in a task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html#setting-the-remote-environment-in-a-task)

Regarding your question

> I haven't found how can I set-up an environment variable that can be used by all tasks following a task.

You can set the environment on [Block](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html) level, a logical groups of tasks too

- [Setting the remote environment](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html): "*When you set a value with environment: at the play or block level, it is available only to tasks within the play or block that are executed by the same user.*"

This means you would need to define a block for the next tasks

```yaml
   - name: Block of next task(s)
     block:
     
     - name: Next task
       ...

     environment:
       CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY: "{{ extract_key2 }}"
```

Regarding your question

> Is it possible to set playbook level environment variable, but after defining some tasks?

No, not on that level in that run as the playbook is already running.

Another option might be to distribute the tasks in question into an other role, playbook or task file and [`include_*`](https://serverfault.com/a/875292/448950) it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `set_fact` a var depending on an other var in the same block. Moreover, there is absolutely no need to `set_fact` here as long as your relevant tasks can live with an empty environment var until it is fully defined. The following environment declaration (untested) should work and return the key for every task running after your file exists.

```yaml
  environment:
    CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY: >-
      {{
        (
          (
            lookup('file', '/export/home/kafusr/kafka/secrets/masterkey.txt', errors='ignore')
            | default('')
          ).split('\n').2
          | default('')
        ).2
        | default('')
        | trim
      }}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Will test this today.  It will create the variable separately on each broker, right?  The text is masterkey.txt is different on each server.

Comment: `The text is masterkey.txt is different on each server` <= lookups only run on the ansible controller so the file lookup will only look for a file available locally.

Comment: I did some lookup and it seems slurp will work on remote servers.  Question is - does it work on local server too?  Will try to formulate the above definition with slurp and post the results ( if I can set it up with slurp )

Comment: Could you give some pointers on how to use slurp when defining environment variable, similar to how you have done using lookup ?